# i have 3 forms on my html website , i want to use google spreadsheets as a databse i need the appropriate code for the appscrip if anyone can assist

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i tried using form submit but it kept sending to spam as i dont want to use captcha. so now i want to try google app script, for multiple forms

```
<form class="custom-form" role="form" action="" method="post">

                            <!-- honeypot -->
                            <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display:none;">
                            <!-- disable captcha -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 my-2">
                                        <label class="mb-2" for="name">Full Name</label>

                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required="">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 my-2">
                                        <label class="mb-2" for="email">Email Address</label>
                                        
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="[^ @]@[^ @]" class="form-control" required="">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 my-2">
                                        <label class="mb-2" for="subject">How did you know about us?</label>

                                        <select class="form-select form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
                                            <option selected="">Choose a subject</option>
                                            <option value="web+search">Website Searches</option>
                                            <option value="social+media">Social Media</option>
                                            <option value="others">Others</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-12 my-2">
                                        <label class="mb-2" for="message">Tell us about the Delivery</label>

                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                                    
                                        <button type="submit" class="form-control mt-4">Submit</button>
                                          </form>
```

this is the second  form of my website i want it to work with appscripts asweell

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <!-- honeypot -->
                            <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display:none;">
                            <!-- disable captcha -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
                            
                                    <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter your full name" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter your address" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="departure_location" placeholder="Departure Location" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="destination_location" placeholder="Destination Location" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-12 my-2">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write to us..."></textarea>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box button">
                                      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                    </div>
                                    <span id="client-msg"></span>
                                  </form>
```

this is the third form of my website i want it to work with appscripts asweell

```
  <form action="" method="POST" />

                                <!-- honeypot -->
                            <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display:none;">
                            <!-- disable captcha -->
                            <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
                            
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="driversfullname" placeholder="Drivers full name" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="driverspassport" placeholder="Drivers Passport Number" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Make" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="horsereg" placeholder="Horse Registration" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="trailertype" placeholder="Trailer Type" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="trailerreg" placeholder="Trailer Registration" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text"name="mileage" placeholder="Mileage" required>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="gitcover" placeholder="GIT Cover" required>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="input-box button">
                                      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                    </div>
                                    <span id="partner-msg"></span>
                                  </form>
```

Comment: Read [this manual](https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet), please. Probably it is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the deployment feature and HTML form to achieve the desired result, I used this post to understand how that works may that helps you as well.
https://www.key2goal.com/article/using-html-submit-form-data-google-speedsheet-using-appscript